# query string sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with my controller, in java spring

**code is:**

```
@Override
    public List<E> equipementsParMotCle(String searchkey, String mc) {
        Query req=em.createQuery("select t from Equipement t where t.equipNumSerie like :x ");
        req.setParameter("x", "%"+mc+"%"); 
        return req.getResultList();
    }
```

I want to execute this function like sql:

```
SELECT Equipement.equipNom,
       Equipement.equipNumSerie,
       Equipement.equipReference,
       Affectation.dateAffectationEmployer,
       Affectation.code,
       Employer.EmpNom,
       Employer.EmpPrenom
FROM Equipement
INNER JOIN Affectation ON Affectation.idAffectation = Equipement.idAffectation
INNER JOIN Employer ON Affectation.EmpID = Employer.EmpID
WHERE Equipement.equipNumSerie = 431514
```

Please how can you convert sql in query controller

Comment: I suppose you need to write it as `CriteriaQuery` and in detail you can use projections or multiselect with tuples.

Comment: this select t from Equipement t where t.equipNumSerie like :x  what is the type of sql ? because is not the simple sql